# Android - unable to get files like pdf on android 10 and above

Tags: android, kotlin

By this code, I successfully got pdf files on below android 10 but on android 10 above pdf files did not shows up in the debugger.

```
  private val fileInfo: ArrayList<PdfFileManagerMC> = ArrayList()


      val rootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath
        val androidDir = File("$rootDir/Android")
        val dataDir = File("$rootDir/data")
        val files: Array<File>? =
            File(rootDir).listFiles()
        if (files != null) {
            for (file in files) {
                if (file != androidDir && file != dataDir)
                    getFiles(file)
            }
        }

   private fun getFiles(root: File) {
        val listAllFiles = root.listFiles()
        if (listAllFiles != null && listAllFiles.isNotEmpty()) {
            for (currentFile in listAllFiles) {
                if (currentFile.name.endsWith(".pdf")) {
                    val temp = PdfFileManagerMC()
                    Log.e("fileManager", currentFile.absolutePath)
                    Log.e("fileManager", currentFile.name)
                    temp.path = currentFile.absolutePath
                    temp.name = currentFile.name
                    fileInfo.add(temp)
                }
            }
            Log.e("fileManager", "" + fileInfo.size)
        }
    }
```

**Note:** Already added runtime permissions and manifest permission also

> android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
>
> ```
> <uses-permission
>     android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
>     tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> ```

Code by `Media Store`:

```
  private fun getPdfList() {
        val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_MODIFIED,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE
        )
////        val  sortOrder = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC"
////        val  selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ?"
        val mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf")
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(mimeType)
        val collection: Uri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
        } else {
            MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
        }
        contentResolver.query(collection, projection, "", selectionArgs, "")
            .use { cursor ->
                assert(cursor != null)
                if (cursor!!.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        val columnData = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA)
                        val name =
                            cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                        val dateModified =
                            cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_MODIFIED)
                        val temp = PdfFileManagerMC()
                        Log.e("fileManager", cursor.getString(columnData))
                        Log.e("fileManager", cursor.getString(name))
                        Log.e("fileManager", cursor.getString(dateModified))
                        temp.path = cursor.getString(columnData)
                        temp.name = name.toString()
                        temp.date = dateModified.toString()
                        fileInfo.add(temp)
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext())
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Use MediaStore to retreivefiles

Comment: also tried that. but it's not working either.

Comment: Paste your code that you used for the purpose of using MediaStore

Comment: `val androidDir = File("$rootDir/Android")
        val dataDir = File("$rootDir/data")` ??? I have never seen a 'data' directory there. What would be possible is :  `val dataDir = File("$androidDir/data")`.

Comment: @blackapps ok but still that's not the reason why I'm not getting files in android 10 above.

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar i have added media store code.

Comment: You should use File.canRead() on your directories before you try to read/listfiles.

Comment: @blackapps ok let me check it.